# Safari extension to clip content to Notes

Tags: safari-extension

Would it be possible to create a Safari that would extract / clip content from the current web page (e.g., a StackOverflow question and the accepted answer, perhaps along with the StackOverflow logo) into a new note in the macOS Notes app? Can an extension access Notes in that way?

If so, I'd greatly appreciate some reference as to how that could be done.

Comment: An extension probably doesn't have access to apps on your computer. You would definitely be able to copy the content to the clipboard (not sure about image with text), and macos MIGHT have something like window's custom protocols (like opening `calculator://test` opens the calculator) to open applications.

Comment: Thanks, @Samathingamajig. I'll take it from the lack of other responses that you are unfortunately correct. I miss my Evernote Web Clipper extension!